# Obtaining active project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In a Visual Studio plugin, I'm trying to obtain the currently active 
project.

I've found some Web posts about using DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects.
That function gives me objects that can be cast to and array of 
DTE.Project objects -- but it always gives me the same project,
regardless of what I've loaded as the current solution in the IDE.
There's always one element in that array, and it's always the same 
element.

Any other way to find the project?

-- Paul

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I ActiveSolutionProjects does what I want -- except that 
it gives bogus information when running a debugging instance of VS2008.
If the plugin is loaded directly into VS2008, I get correct information.

Comment: Should you need the `Object` use: `DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects(0).Object`

Answer (score 0):

I used this code from the article at [Get active project - Extending Visual Studio SharePoint development tools tip #1](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/active-project-extending-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools-tip-1/). Relax, no SharePoint work needed. I'll show the code here but best read the article for info on some changes you may need in your project file.

```
internal static Project GetActiveProject()
{
    DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
    return GetActiveProject(dte);
}

internal static Project GetActiveProject(DTE dte)
{
    Project activeProject = null;

    Array activeSolutionProjects = dte.ActiveSolutionProjects as Array;
    if (activeSolutionProjects != null && activeSolutionProjects.Length > 0)
    {
        activeProject = activeSolutionProjects.GetValue(0) as Project;
    }

    return activeProject;
}
```